# Homebrew no longer working after macOS upgrade, perl errors

Tags: macos, perl, homebrew

I am getting the following error or similar whenever I run any command with `brew` (for instance, `brew cleanup`). I am using a MacBook Pro running  macOS 14.1.2, and a system update was downloaded just this morning.

```
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-ruby/blobs/sha256:02180ca8b8295422ae84921bcf034b7ee8ce5575488bd5e6a37a192e53cd5d34
############################################################################################################################################################ 100.0%
Can't locate strict.pm:   /Network/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/strict.pm: Permission denied at /usr/bin/shasum5.30 line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/shasum5.30 line 21.
Error: Checksum mismatch.
Expected: 02180ca8b8295422ae84921bcf034b7ee8ce5575488bd5e6a37a192e53cd5d34
  Actual:
 Archive: /Users/williamdewey/Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-3.1.4.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
Error: Failed to install Homebrew Portable Ruby (and your system version is too old)!
```

I confirmed perl is installed with `perl -v`, I have version 5.30.3. `which perl` says `/usr/bin/perl`

XCode Commmand Line tools appear to be up to date.

I tried changing permissions and discovered that /Network/Library doesn't exist at all, nor any of the subdirectories. (Why is the script looking in Network anyway when perl is installed on my Mac? I don't understand).

Most answers I have found assume some knowledge of Perl, but I am not familiar with the language. I did find this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448661/perl-issue-on-os-x-el-capitan
Trying `perl -E 'say for @INC'`  from the above. I get another error:

```
Can't locate feature.pm:   /Network/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/feature.pm: Permission denied.
```

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: *"Can't locate strict.pm:   /Network/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/strict.pm"*  Could it be that the `/Network/Library` has been deleted by accident? If so, is there a way to restore it? If you upgrade macOS, doesn't it upgrade the Perl installation also? So that might be one way to restore it?

Comment: Yes, it seems that a system upgrade will occasionally update the perl version, see: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252804988?sortBy=best

Comment: Another approach to repair the missing files, could be to install exactly the same perl version 5.30.3 with perlbrew, and then copy missing modules from that installation to `/Network/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level` until `brew` starts working again

Comment: Appears to be a permission issue. `Permission denied` accessing a fundamental Perl files, `strict.pm` and `feature.pm`. Fix your filepermissions!

Comment: Checked on my own mac now which is running macOS 13.1 but the system perl is still at version 5.30.3. There the `strict.pm` is located in `/System/Library` instead of `/Network/Library`. Could it be that the system upgrade relocated the `/Network/Library` folder to `/System/Library` ?

Comment: which `perl` are you actually using? Homebrew's `perl`? macOS's bundled `perl`? running `which perl` in the terminal would be helpful. But given the `/Network/Library`, I suspect you're trying to run `perl` off a network share/drive that isn't mounted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a permission issue (as indicated by `Permission denied`) accessing fundamental Perl files `strict.pm` and `feature.pm`. Fix the file permissions for `/Network/Library/Perl` and its descendants so that you can access them.

This should do:

```perl
sudo find /Network/Library/Perl -depth -exec chmod go+rX {} \;
```

That's an uppercase `X`.

I think Macs don't support `-exec +`, so I used the slower `-exec ;` instead.

Comment: /Network/Library/Perl didn't exist, but running the same command on just /Network solved the issue. (The perl files were actually in System/Library/Perl but for some reason it was looking in /Network first).